Trying to understand the value of SAR and DAR in video/FFmpeg?
I convert video using the FFmpeg utility to WEBM format using Dash technology.
I convert one video, focusing on the frame height. In resolution (frame height):

2160p
1440p
1080p
720p
480p
360p
240p
144p

The frame width can be any, I compress, bring the frame to the required height, and the width is proportionally adapted relative to the specified height
I don't quite understand what role the parameter plays SAR and DAR.
Is it worth setting different values ​​for each height, how will this affect the quality of video viewing for the user?
What if we add to all the listed qualities:
sar=1:1,
dar=16:9

What are the possible negative consequences in different situations?

It doesn't sound to me that you would want to mess with either of them. Rather you set w to -1. And assuming you are talking about the params for the scale filter, you probably need/want to mess with sar and dar only if the input file does not have proper metadata. And these days you would hardly need to deal with non-1:1 sar sources, except when the input is e.g. video stream from a DVD (or digitization of analog sources from a similar / earlier time). See this for some more details.

So these parameters are becoming a thing of the past and can be forgotten?
